# Thymeleaf: обновлять таблицу с сервера каждые 30 секунд

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, thymeleaf

Есть такая таблца:

```
<table id="full_balance_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Category</th>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <if th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(fullBalanceRecordList)}">
        <tr th:each="overallBalanceRecord : ${fullBalanceRecordList}">
           <td type="text" th:text="${overallBalanceRecord.date != null} ? ${#calendars.format(overallBalanceRecord.date, 'dd.MM.yyyy')} : null"></td>
           <td th:text="${overallBalanceRecord.category}"></td>
           <td th:text="${overallBalanceRecord.title}"></td>
           <td th:text="${overallBalanceRecord.sign}"></td>
           <td type="number" th:text="${overallBalanceRecord.value}"></td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

данные в нее могут приходить от нескольких пользователей, следовательно хочу сделать обновление таблицы каждые 30 секунд без перезагрузки самой страницы. В качестве источника данных просто кладу значению в мапу в контроллере:

`map.put("fullBalanceRecordList", balanceService.balanceRecordList());`

Использую thymeleaf и datatables
В datatables пробовал сделать нечто такое

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
   ajax: "/refresh"
} );

setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 30000 );
```

Но получаю ошибку 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Template name cannot be null or empty`

Вопрос в том как сделать обновление таблицы каждые 30 секунд?

**UPD** @enzo

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/refresh", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String refreshBalanceTable() {

    String jsonResult = new Gson().toJson(balanceService.balanceRecordList());
    jsonResult = "{ \"data\":".join(jsonResult).join("}");
    return jsonResult;
}
```

Когда делаю в datatables все время вылетает это https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

Comment: `DataTables` данные [через JSON обновляет](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)..Вам их для Thymeleaf в модель вообще не надо передавать, просто нарисовать пустую таблицу, и добавить еще один URL с которого вы будуете дергать JSON. Хинт: `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: Ну по той ссылке, что вы дали, прям детально же все разжевано. :) Скорее всего причина тут `DataTables will fire a specific error for the case where the request from the server is a valid return (200 Ok for example), but not valid JSON`. Посмотрите, что там за JSON и пройдитесь по нему [валидатором](http://jsonlint.com/). Потом, вы же JSON как строку возвращаете, а `Content-Type` правильный кто будет указывать?

Comment: Когда указал content type, ошибка перестала появляться, json валидный, но в таблице ничего не появляется

Comment: Я не экстрасенс, бесконечно угадывать не могу. Учитесь дебажить JS.

Comment: Дебаг `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined`

Comment: 1. Если отдаете  объект, то нужно [мапить столбцы](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/deepObjects.html) 2. [Тынц](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28318291/5694145)

Comment: @Enzo Спасибо, можно считать за правильный ответ